# How to add values to multiple variables into one single variable? | C#

Tags: c#, variables, decimal, addition

How to add values to multiple variables into one single variable in the C#?

For example, I declared three variables

```
decimal number1 = 53m;

decimal number2 = 33m;

decimal total;
```

Now, when I do like this

```
total = number1 + number2;
```

**It gives an error "use of unassigned local variable"**

Even this won't work

```
total = number1;  
total = number2;
```

It also doesn't work

```
total += number1 
total += number2
```

I knew in textboxes we do like this, so, I thought it can work for variable also but it's not.

```
totaltextbox.text += textbox.text1  
totaltextbox.text += textbox.text2
```

> EDIT:

Now it is working after I assigned every value in the declaration to each variable.

Earlier I only assigned them in the if statements and that was causing problem. Have a look on my method for example,

```
private decimal OilLubeCharges()
        {
           decimal oilChange_var=0m;
           decimal lubeJob_var=0m;
           decimal oilLube_var=0m;
           decimal totalOiltLubeCharges_var=0m;


            if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                oilChange_var = 26.00m;

            }

            else if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                lubeJob_var = 18.00m;
            }

            else if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked && lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                oilLube_var = 26.00m + 18.00m;
            }

            totalOiltLubeCharges_var = oilChange_var + lubeJob_var + oilLube_var;
```

I don't understand if I have given variables a value in the if statement then also it should work. Why they need a value to be given in the start?

Thanks to all who put their effort. Respect!

Comment: I doubt that your example of `total = number1;` wouldn't work, get rid of any other lines and that should work fine.

Comment: Share a complete code example, the code you have provided, if you have declared the `decimal` variables in that order, should work just fine.

Comment: The reason that `totaltextbox.text += textbox.text1` works is because the `Text` property of a `TextBox` is initialized when the constructor of the `TextBox` is called. The `+=` (add assignment) operator simply replaces the string within the `Text` property with the current string and the new string concatenated.

Comment: check answer you code is working fine

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Using *only* those 4 lines works. Please post the the *exact line* where the error occurs

Comment: @Marcus I edited my question please check.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my question please check.

Comment: @Ninja the new code has nothing to do with the old. In order to get a meaningful answer, you should post code that actually reproduces the error. Even here, if `total` isn't assigned the code will compile. `oilLube_var` on the other hand may *never* be assigned. The compiler knows this and would complain if you used ` decimal oilLube_var;`

Comment: `oilLube_var` is assigned a value of `0` on the third row. I think the actual issue must be that one of your checkboxes does not hold a value. Can you tell us excactly what exceptions/errors you are getting please, on what row?

Comment: Yes, @PanagiotisKanavos that's what I did earlier. I didn't assign any value to the variable in the declaration. Only I assigned it in if statements, but that didn't worked until I gave a 0 value to each variable in declaration

Comment: @marcus I didn't do rest of the coding because I was stuck here. I think it will be fine with now as what I did i.e assigned zero to each in declaring the variable. I'm still wondering why I need to give zero in declaring the variable. I gave it a value in if statements so it should have worked that way also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of unassigned local variable means:

```
decimal total;
```

This has been declared, but it has no value **and you are trying to use it before it has a value**. There is no assignment here.

So you initialise it:

```
decimal total = 0;
```

Your problem now goes away.

However, this will **only be an error** if you try and use an unintialised variable.

So technically:

```
decimal val1 = 10;
decimal val2 = 10;

decimal total;

total = val1 + val2; // this works
```

This is also the same as

```
decimal total = val1 + val2; // an assignment.
```

### What won't work

```
decimal total; // compiler knows you want a total variable

if (total > 10) // at this point, there is no value in total so how can we compare it
{
    Console.WriteLine("This won't compile");
}
```

### Looking at your problem

```
private decimal OilLubeCharges()
{
   // this is what i **think** you might have started with
   decimal oilChange_var;
   decimal lubeJob_var;
   decimal oilLube_var;
   decimal totalOiltLubeCharges_var;


    if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        oilChange_var = 26.00m;

    }

    else if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        lubeJob_var = 18.00m;
    }

    else if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked && lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        oilLube_var = 26.00m + 18.00m;
    }

    totalOiltLubeCharges_var = oilChange_var + lubeJob_var + oilLube_var;
```

It is simple here, because you have defined you variables up top, you are then using `if` statements to define whether or not these variables get set. **Which means there is a possibility that they wont have a value**. This is because of this line

```
totalOiltLubeCharges_var = oilChange_var + lubeJob_var + oilLube_var;
```

Here you are **categorically** using all the variables. But before that line you're **conditionally** giving them an **initial** value.

So for instance if `lubeJobCheckBox.Checked` is false, then your `lubeJob_var` has never been given an initial value. So you **can't use it**.

Comment: Yes, I started doing that way earlier. Much appreciated for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

This example may be help you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal number1 = 53m;

        decimal number2 = 33m;

        decimal total; 

        total = number1 + number2; 

        Console.WriteLine(total);
    }
}
}
```

http://rextester.com/CTJQ60331

[image]

Comment: This is not a "solution", it is a duplicate of the OPs question material.

Comment: Then explain it in the answer, don't force people to guess what you wanted to say. `This example may be help you.` doesn't imply "Your code should compile and here is the proof"

Comment: i am telling code is working fine but marcus is saying are you copy of code.

Comment: Then edit your question and make it clear. As it is, it is *not* a good answer

Comment: Thanks for tell me

Answer (score -2):

you need to assign some value to total first.

```
    decimal total=0;
```

or

```
    decimal total = number1 + number2;
```

Comment: You need to see time difference. It can happen.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect anyways, a defined variable does not need an initial value to be assignable, that would be extremely limiting.

Comment: Time difference is, mine was answered 9 minutes ago and yours 7 (as of this comment).

Comment: But he is in another dimension.

Comment: You *don't* need to assign anything, if the first use of the variable is actually an assignment. The code *int the question* works as is. The OP probably didn't include the line that actually fails